# High Training Accuracy, Poor Validation, Test Accuracy

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, rnn

I am a beginner exploring Deep learning. I am trying to train a classifier (9 classes) with images as the input to my CNN followed by Bidirectional LSTM architecture.

My model rapidly achieves a very high training accuracy (98-100%) but the test and validation accuracy remains constant at 15-20%.

[image: Blue line is the training accuracy. Green is validation accuracy and yellow is test accuracy]

In the above image, blue line is the training accuracy. Green is validation accuracy and yellow is test accuracy

[image: Loss which is being propagated backwards]

In the above image, the blue line is the loss which is being propagated backwards

What could be the possible reason for this peculiarity? Any suggestions to overcome this poor test accuracy dilemma would be appreciated.

Additional Info: I have 630 training samples, 90 test samples and 90 samples for validation. I have implemented early stopping to stop training once my validation error stops decreasing in a patience interval.

```
# Convolutional Neural Network

class ConvNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,num_classes=9):
    super(ConvNet,self).__init__()
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=16,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2),
        nn.Dropout(0.25)#dropout_factor = 0.1
    )

    self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3,stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2),
        nn.Dropout(0.25)#dropout_factor = 0.1
    )

    self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32,out_channels=8,kernel_size=2,stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(8),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2),
        nn.Dropout(0.25)#dropout_factor = 0.1
    )

    self.flc = nn.Linear(8*16*32,1024)

    self.hidden_size = 9
    self.num_layers = 2

    self.blstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=1024,hidden_size=9,num_layers=2,batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)

    self.flc2 = nn.Linear(18,9) #(hidden_size*2, num_classes) %2 for bidirection


def forward(self,x):
    out = self.layer1(x)
    out = self.layer2(out)
    out = self.layer3(out)
    out = out.reshape(out.size(0),1,4096) #Flatten tensor
    out = self.flc(out)

    h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, out.size(0), self.hidden_size) # 2 for bidirection 
    c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, out.size(0), self.hidden_size)

    # Forward propagate LSTM
    out, _ = self.blstm(out, (h0, c0))  # out: tensor of shape (batch_size, seq_length, hidden_size*2)
    # Decode the hidden state of the last time step
    out = self.flc2(out[:, -1, :])
    return out
```

Comment: @oW_♦  sorry for the late edit. Could you please see if my question is clear now? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your model is not learning by generalizing the data in the training set but memorizing it, hence good training accuracy but bad test accuracy. For us to figure out the problem, we need information about the data i.e. what are these images and what is your task and what is the reason behind using bidirectional LSTM for an image classification task. Also provide the architecture of your model for us to see if there is any errors in the architecture that you are using.

Comment: The images are spectrograms. The axes to a spectrogram are time and frequency respectively. Hence I decided to use a bidirectional LSTM. 

I have edited the question to include the code for the architecture. 
What steps can I take to allow for greater generalization? I have included dropouts and a regularization factor (weight decay) already.